# Where to find custom Content type related files in Drupal directories?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a localhost Drupal 7.x installation on my system. I have just explored with UI and created a custom Content type which defines a form with radio boxes. (Home --> Structure --> Content types --> Add Content Type, and so on.)

I am assuming these custom content types will be stored in local directories of Drupal core. I am not able to figure out where exactly these stay. I am curious to make changes to that file and see if there is any reflection, though I am not sure if it works that way.

Comment: Hi friend, when you talk about "Stored in local directories", Do you mean about a file atached to a content, or are you talking about  the whole custom content?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, content is managed through the database, so you won't find a specific dir named Content Types in the drupal folder.